# How I can create random uniform integer numbers using numpy.random.rand() in the range for example $[-10,10)$?

Tags: python, numpy

How I can create random uniform integer numbers using numpy.random.rand() in the range for example [-10,10)?

I tried (10 * (2 * np.random.rand(10000) - 1)).astype(int) but in this case for example probability of having -10 is less than probability of any other integer. Is there a way to push left endpoint to -11?

Comment: You could use `np.random.randint(low=-10, high=10, size=10000)` instead: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs I know, but I want with random.rand()

Comment: Ah, my apologies, I wasn't sure :)

Comment: What about something like `(np.random.rand(10000) * 20).astype(int) - 10`?

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs my bad, thanks, this will work :)

Comment: Glad I could help despite jumping the gun on randint... ;) have a great day